# How to write a Nested for loops for numbers starting larger than 0

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a Nested for loops for my school assignment that will print this, exactly like this, you cant change the starting number

```
    10
    11 12 
    13 14 15
    16 17 18 19
    20 21 22 23 24
    25 26 27 28 29 30
    31 32 33 34 35 36 37
    38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
    46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54
```

so far I wrote this

```js
var i, col, row, number, text;

text = ' ' ;
number = 10;

for(col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
  for (row = 0; row <= col; row++) {
    text+=row;
    text+="<br>";
    
    console.log(text)
  }
}
```

The problem is that it starts from number 0, not 10. I also need to use a for loops to do it.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish. What are the numbers in the first block?

Comment: just a tip, ask only one question/problem in one question and another, try to solve the triabgle with a better starting number and add an offset to get the wanted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a growing offset. This values starts with `10` and increments for each line with the item count of one line.

The you need another loop to collect the values for a line. After collecting show the values.

```js
var lines = 9,
    offset = 10,
    length = 1;

while (length <= lines) {
    console.log(...Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => offset + i));
    offset += length++;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With output as html.

```js
var lines = 9,
    offset = 10,
    length = 1,
    element = document.getElementById("output");

while (length <= lines) {
    element.innerHTML += Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => offset + i).join(' ') + '\n';
    offset += length++;
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Wow your so smart, is that the most efficient way you can do it?

Comment: actually yes . . .

Comment: How do I make it print on the screen instead of console log

Answer (score 2):

To start the for loop at 1 simply replace the `for(col = 0` with `for(col = 1`

---

For the box:

```
let n = 5
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(i === 0 || i === n-1){
            console.log("o")
        } else if (j === 0 || j === n-1) {
            console.log("o")
        }
    }
}
```

should do it (I have not tested it)

Comment: But that will make it so that it only print 8 and put a large space on the top of the page. I need it to start at 10 look at the example

Comment: ``for(col = 0; col <= 10``  ==>  ``for(col = 1; col <= 11``

Comment: Dude your code gives me https://gyazo.com/35e75e859300281fc1171c782d09dadb.  I gave a example of how I wanted it in the top part. Which is startinng from number 10 not 1 or 0 And also can you make a box, you can't make the box in console.log?

Answer (score 0):

a lot of trial and error with the maths but it works

```js
let startnumber = 10;
let iterations = 10;

for (let i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
    let temp = "";
    for (let j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        temp += (j-Math.floor((i*i)/2+i/2))*-1+startnumber + " ";
    }   
    console.log(temp);
}
```